# Consumer key secret being shown to the user [PARSE SERVER]

Tags: android, twitter-oauth, twitter4j, parse-server

I'm seeing the "authData" field in the parse server dashboard, and I saw that users can have access to my (consumer key secret) from twitter.
Here is the data I see:
[

```
{
   "twitter": {
     "consumer_key": "XXXXYAJ",
     "auth_token": "ABCDCODESAMPLEXXX87",
     "screen_name": "nameUserSample",
     "consumer_secret": "HEREISSHOWINGMYCONSUMERKEYSECRET",
     "id": "7777777777777",
     "auth_token_secret": "SECR3TAUTHTOK3N"
   }
}
```

What are the risks of the user being able to see my consumer key secret? Can I avoid this somehow? Thank you!

This is my code to login:

```
bt_conectarTwitter.setCallback(new com.twitter.sdk.android.core.Callback<TwitterSession>() {
            @Override
            public void success(Result<TwitterSession> result) {
                dialogLoading.showDialog(getContext());
                // Do something with result, which provides a TwitterSession for making API calls
                Log.i("lul", "success: " + result);

                TwitterSession session = TwitterCore.getInstance().getSessionManager().getActiveSession();
                TwitterAuthToken authToken = session.getAuthToken();
                final String tokenUserTwitter = authToken.token;
                final String secretTokenUserTwitter = authToken.secret;
                final String userId = String.valueOf(session.getUserId());
                final String userName = session.getUserName();
                   ParseTwitterUtils.logIn(userId,userName,tokenUserTwitter,secretTokenUserTwitter, new LogInCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException err) {
                        if (user == null) {
                            Log.d("MyApp", "Uh oh. The user cancelled the Twitter login.");
                        } else if (user.isNew()) {
                            newUserFromTwitter();
                            saveTokensTwitter(tokenUserTwitter,secretTokenUserTwitter);
                            Log.d("MyApp", "User signed up and logged in through Twitter!");
                        } else {
                            if (ParseTwitterUtils.isLinked(user)){
                                String authToken =  ParseTwitterUtils.getTwitter().getAuthToken();
                                String secretToken = ParseTwitterUtils.getTwitter().getAuthTokenSecret();
                                saveTokensTwitter(authToken,secretToken);
                            }
                            Log.d("MyApp", "User logged in through Twitter!");
                            goToMainActivity();
                        }
                    }
                });


//                saveTokensTwitter(tokenUserTwitter,secretTokenUserTwitter);

                Log.i("lul", "success: " + authToken.token);
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterException exception) {
                // Do something on failure
                Log.i("lul", "fail: " + "fail");
            }
        });
```

And I'm using this button:

```
 <com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.TwitterLoginButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:id="@+id/bt_conectarTwitter"/>
```

You can see the Doc's from this button [here](https://github.com/twitter/twitter-kit-android/wiki/Log-In-with-Twitter)

Comment: How exactly did that data get there? What configurations did you add? Why are users accessing Parse directly rather than an API abstraction with your business logic?

Comment: Hello, I started by logging in with twitter, following the documentation here: https://docs.parseplatform.org/android/guide/#twitter-users

Malicious "users" can only look at network traffic and see all the information that is linked to your account, if the user signs in with twitter, the information I showed above will be there, and can be easily read.

Comment: Read over https://docs.parseplatform.org/android/guide/#security , specifically, as I mentioned, implement an API layer (such as Cloud Code), that the clients actually interact with to implement your "business logic" rather than giving them straight database access.

Comment: If anything, storing your own Twitter SDK keys along with any user object seems like a design flaw. Those should be stored elsewhere in the database to possibly be shared by all accounts that interact with your Twitter application, but not copy amongst each user

Comment: The twitter SDK in the client’s require you to have the client_secret client side. So the design flaw is in the twitter SDK. How you overcome it is on your responsibility. As for the parse side, only the id and access token are required to be sent by the android SDK. The client key/secret should be configured on the server

Comment: @flovilmart Do you know any way to solve this? Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: Why do you pass the client_secret in the first place? you should not need it with the twitter button. parse-server doesn't require it from the client but only from the server. as for wether the android SDK requires it for twitter, you should probably open an issue on the relevant repository.